# Dropdowns content is wider than dropdown

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I've created a dropdown component in React. I want the component to be reusable, and for that reason I want it to expand its with to fill 100% of whatever container it gets put into. My current problem is, that both my dropdown button and my dropdown content has a width of 100%. The dropdown button expands to fill with width of its container, however the dropdown content expands much more, as its position is absolute.

How can I make the dropdown content the same width as the dropdown button?

I've created an example on codesandbox.

Direct link: https://p34wl136rj.codesandbox.io/

Link to editor: https://codesandbox.io/s/p34wl136rj

Answer (score 2):

Its because the dropdown menu has the `position:absolute` and it gets the width of closest parent that has `position:relative` . 
try this :

```
.dropdown {
   position: relative;
}
```